# How to start ReactJS project in ABP template?

Tags: reactjs, aspnetboilerplate

I'm new to the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework. I just downloaded the template, which builds with .NET Core and React.js, from ABP website "Get started" page. I created the database and updated the database. The database seems correct, now I don't know how to run it.

I set the **Workflow.Web.Host.csproj** as the startup project and ran it. I just got a page with a list of APIs.

My question is how can I login to the system by React.js?

Answer (score 0):

From [reactjs/README.md](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/v5.0.0/reactjs/README.md) in the downloaded template:

> After cloning repository, first install npm packages:
>
> ```sh
> cd reactjs
> npm install
> ```
>
> And then start:
>
> ```sh
> npm start
> ```